# Angularjs-ui-route: transition animation not working

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui-router, css-animations

angular js version: 1.5.6

I am trying to add animation when `state` is changed but things are not going well and I am not able to figure out whats going wrong. Please help.

**What have I done?**

There are 3 tabs as you can see in the snipet I have attached. Default there color is yellow but When they enter I want there color to be red. So I have written this css:

```
.tab {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.main{
    -webkit-transition: all 30s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 30s ease;
    transition: all 30s ease;

    &.ng-enter{ 
        .tab{
            background-color: red;
        }
    }

}
```

Then I applied `main` css on the ui-view

```
<div ui-view ng-class="main"></div>
```

**Whole Code**

```js
var MyApp = angular
  .module('MyApp', [
    'ui.router',
    'ngAnimate'
  ])
  .config(function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('tab1', {
        url: "/tab1",
        template: `<div class="tab">
  <h3>Tab 1</h3>
  my content
</div>`
      })
      .state('tab2', {
        url: "/tab2",
        template: `<div class="tab">
  <h3>Tab 2</h3>
 content of tab 2
</div>`
      })
      .state('tab3', {
        url: "/tab3",
        template: `<div class="tab">
  <h3>Tab 3</h3>
 tab 3 content
</div>`
      });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab1');

  });
```

```css
.tab {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.main {
  -webkit-transition: all 30s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 30s ease;
  transition: all 30s ease;
  &.ng-enter {
    .tab {
      background-color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.6/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.6/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="MyApp">
  <header>
    <nav>
      <a ui-sref="tab1">Tab 1</a>
      <a ui-sref="tab2">Tab 2</a>
      <a ui-sref="tab3">Tab 3</a>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <div>
    <div ui-view ng-class="main"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found some mistakes in your code. First, when you're using `ng-class` directive you should use expression, and you just set it to a class name. So you should use simple `class` attribute in this case. And also you have some mistakes in your css. It looks like [less](http://lesscss.org/). I've corrected it, like this:

```
.tab {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.main.ng-enter {
  -webkit-transition: all 30s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 30s ease;
  transition: all 30s ease;

}

.main.ng-enter .tab{
      background-color: red;
}
```

You can see working example [here](https://jsbin.com/qeyoxuqugi/1/edit?html,css,js,output). In example I put `transition-time` equals to 1s for clarity.

Comment: Could you please elaborate the process. how does this css works? I know I am asking for more but it will help noobs like me. Many thanks Sergey..many thanks. and you said that my css looks like `less`, what does it mean? :D :) :P

Comment: Also, It works only if I click on a link. If I open it by url then it does not work. do u have any idea?

Comment: First, less is preprocessor for css. Your css code syntax looks like less syntax. You can learn more about less [here](http://lesscss.org/). Second, when you're click the link, angular creates new `.main` `ui-view` element with `ng-enter` class and to previous element it adds `ng-leave` class, and then removes previous element. Here's another [example](https://jsbin.com/qiwicapeza/edit?html,css,js,output) for you. You can learn more about animations [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations). And third, I think when you open the page by link angular doesn't add `ng-enter` class...

Comment: one last question could you tell me if it is possible to show the animation transition on URL change by entering a URL in address bar (just like it happens on link click) because the animation is not working if I am changing the URL from address bar. Tons of thanks for everything.

Comment: Well, I've tried to find something, but I've stumbled on [these](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5130). It's seems impossible to achieve what you want to do...

Comment: you have already done a lot for me. Many thanks. and if i found anything related I will surely let you know